# Android Listview Search/Filter and Multi Select is not working properly

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview for product search/filter and multiple select option.
After select any item when I'm searching another item filter option working properly but select position is not changing.

View my [Problem video](https://youtu.be/8fdoXkHCRsk).

Comment: You have to set your listview using model class and change its checked behaviour in model class itself.

Answer (score 0):

After select any item when I'm searching another item filter option working properly but select position is not changing.

Because in case of listview'method ( getView() ) maintain(keep checked records in memory) only for those items which are currently visible , in your case you checked first item and searched (in this case first item changed with new values).

So i would suggest you to start keeping record on your own side , like :-

keep checked record in

```
Map <Integer,Boolean> map=new HashMap<>();
```

And when user click on list item put item position and checkbox checked status inside **Map** . And check/uncheck the checkbox before check that this value is 
true or false in Map

Or you can use pojo file to keep record of every clicked item corresponding to unique id

This example can help you if you go with pojo class :-
http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html